# Core Data Model Design: use a single complex Entity or group homogeneous attributes in other entities?

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design

I am dealing with a very complex Entity which has several homogeneous attributes that could be grouped in some kind of "macro categories".

To extremely simplify lets’ think about an Entity, myCar, with only two macro categories: “financial attributes” and “physical attributes”:

**Financial attributes**: cost, resale value, annual expenses.

**Physical attributes**: height, width, weight, color.

I have two options to model it:

***Option 1***: Store all the attributes in a single Entity:

Single Entity: **MyCar** with the following attributes:

- cost
- resale value
- annual expenses
- height
- width
- weight
- color

***Option 2***: Use three entities and two relationships to model it:

Entity 1:   **MyCar**

- 1 to 1 relationship 1: Financials
- 1 to 1 relationship 2: Physicals

Entity 2:   **Financials**

- cost
- resale value
- annual expenses
- 1 to 1 relationship: myCar

Entity 3:   **Physicals**

- Height
- Width
- Weight
- Color
- 1 to 1 relationship: myCar

Up to now I always used Option 1 but thinking about how the data should be displayed on a Pad, inside an UISplitViewController with “Financials” and “Physicals” options in the master side on the left and related attributes in the detail side on the right, I thought about option 2.

Which is the better approach to model this complex Entity with Core Data? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice should be about which data you need at any time. If you always need all of the data then using multiple entities offers little value. If however you have a master view which lists only a subset of the data and a detail view which lists all data then it is very beneficial to separate the data into different entities based around that usage. This limits the amount of data that will be faulted as you scroll through the master list and improves performance.

That doesn't mean that you shouldn't also set the fetch request batch quantity which is also a massive factor in how effective and smooth your scrolling will be...